# Insert Command in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to execute an "INSERT INTO" command by using the asp:SqlDataSource InsertCommand in a C# statement ".Insert()".

The Button, "btninsert", resides in the header field of a gridview as does the inserting Textboxes: "TextBoxHeadercol1", "TextBoxHeadercol2" and "TextBoxHeadercol3".

I have 4 columns in my table, "test", they are "idt", "col1", "col2", "col3".  My Gridview is "gvtotal".

I know that col1, col2 and col3 will print no data because I left out ItemTemplate with the labels.

```
public void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col1"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvtotal.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol1")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col2"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvtotal.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol2")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["col3"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvtotal.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol3")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
<asp:GridView ID="gvtotal"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="idt">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idt" HeaderText="idt" Readonly="true" SortExpression="idt" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol1" text="col1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col2">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol2" text="col2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col3">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol3" text="col3" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" Text="Insert Into" OnClick="btninsert_Click" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connone %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test];"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] [col1],[col2],[col3] VALUES @col1,@col2,@col3;"
    runat="server"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get away with this by using InsertCommand template provided by SQLDataSource. Write this command for SQLDataSource for

InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Test(….) VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3)

Use SQLDataSource template to map @val1, @val2 and @val3 to text boxes you want. The provided quick template will facilitate this. In the click event for Insert, simply refresh grid view view to display the new contents

```
public void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview.DataBind();
}
```

*Note that I do not have Visul Studio on my machine. Assume the above code as pseudo code*